# Highlight not working even with highlight field added

Tags: elasticsearch

Added Highlight in my query but it is not appearing in the result.

I have added hightlight this way shown in the code:

```
"highlight": {
"fields": {
  "*": {

      }
    } 
  }
```

I am expecting that there will be a field called highlight when JSON result is resturned.

Answer (score 0):

From docs:

> Highlighters enable you to get highlighted snippets from one or more
>   fields in your search results so you can show users where the query
>   matches are.

You need to search on something for hightlight to show. So in query part do a text search
ex

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "<fieldName>": <fieldValue>
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "status": {}
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks, for the prompt reply. I do have the query part. But highlighted part is still not appearing. I have changed "*" to "status", but is still not working

Comment: Can you add your full query and response